# Telegram bot: Restrict sender list

Tags: bots, telegram, restrict, sender

I'm using a Telegram bot for downloading images sent to it automatically. The images are shown in a presentation immediately after download, so I need to make sure that only group members should be allowed to send to the bot.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.message.from.id` to identify users.

And `getChatMember` method:
[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: Thanks, I‘ll give that a try.